# Windows phone 8 emulator not showing maps

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am trying to create a windows phone 8 application but the emulator does not show me the map. all I get is this.

[image: No Map Land]
as you can see no land mass is show and no roads are shown. I have panned around and come across nothing and the emulator location is set to an area where land should show.

If I run it on my device it works fine and the map loads.

Could this be due to a port blocking issue or something silly like that.

Cheers
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Maps are not supported on the Windows Phone 8 emulator.</s>

Maps are now supported, and the original question is no longer valid.

Comment: Cheers mate. I thought it was going to be something simple.

Comment: I have a map in the simulator as we speak, and there are demo's on Microsoft site that demo it.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it's because it's a Windows Phone **7** emulator you have running. The maps component is very explicit about printing "Maps are not supported" when viewed in the emulator ;)

Comment: Windows Phone 8 emulator does support maps.  That's the whole point of the location tab off the chevron.  Here's a post from Igor that talks about a reg hack to get rid of a blank maps screen - http://igrali.com/2012/07/30/windows-phone-location-tool-in-emulator-down-no-problem/ .

Comment: -1 totally incorrect. I just opened the emulator, clicked maps and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

The approved answer might not be 100% correct. Check out the following blog post, and you will notice, that your emulator probably doesn't have an access to the internet.
http://michalstawarz.pl/2013/01/26/windows-phone-8-emulator-maps-display/

Answer (score 2):

**Windows Phone emulator supports Bing Map for sure.**

It seems the Problem may be due to

1. Network Connectivity Issues with Host PC
2. Proxy Issues
3. Other Issues

**Workaround for the above Issues.**

If you see blank blue map screen as in http://michalstawarz.pl/2013/01/26/windows-phone-8-emulator-maps-display/  as Michael referred.

Then its good to go. Problem is Internet connectivity / proxy not configured.

**If its is Network Connectivity,** then troubleshoot your system network adapter. Problem may be due to limited network connectivity / PC not connected to internet.

**If it is proxy** then,

1. Get IP Address of "Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator
   Internal Switch" using IPCONFIG in CMD prompt
2. Then Enter it under Exception List in IE's LAN Settings >> Advanced >> Exception

**Other Issues** may be due to Not Configured / improper IP configuration when adapter's IP setting changed manually.

If it is the case -- then Remove all virtual adapters using Virtual Switch Manager Menu in Hyper-V Manager and RUN Emulator with ADMIN Privileges.

Answer (score 0):

If the answers from Micheal and Prakash doesn't solve your problem.Then try this-

1. Open regedit in the *C:\Windows* folder.
2. In Registry Editor open

   for 64 bit Windows-

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\InternetExplorer\MAIN
   \FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION and then create XDETools.exe with hex value 2328.

   for 64 bit Windows-

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InternetExplorer\MAIN
   \FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION and then create XDETools.exe with hex value 2328.

**Source**-http://igrali.com/2012/07/30/windows-phone-location-tool-in-emulator-down-no-problem/